# Property of surjective submersions?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$, $N$ and $P$ be smooth manifolds and $f:M\longrightarrow N$ and $g:N\longrightarrow P$ be two smooth maps. Let us write $h:=g\circ f:M\longrightarrow P$.

Suppose $h$ is a surjective submersion and $f$ is surjective. Does this imply $g$ is a surjective submersion?

Thanks.

Comment: Compositions of surjections are surjections. This applies to manifolds and to tangent spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Since $h$ is surjective, $g$ is surjective. This is true for any maps of sets satisfying the hypotheses. By the chain rule,
$$
dh_x = dg_{f(x)}\circ df_x,
$$
and $dh_x$ is surjective. Thus we glean that $dg_{f(x)}$ is surjective, so that $g$ is a submersion at $f(x)$. Since any point $y\in N$ may be written $f(x)$ for some $x\in M$, $dg_y$ is surjective for all $y\in N$, so $g$ is a submersion. Putting it all together, $g$ is a surjective submersion.